# Zipping file in perl

Tags: perl

I have been trying to zip files on remote windows server but not getting success by whatever i tried. Below is the small peice of code. Please tell me where m going wrong. This code is not producing any error but just not generating the zip file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# before running check perl module is installed in your PC.

use Archive::Zip;
use File::Basename 'basename';

my @files = ('D:\Scripts\Testing\abc.txt');    
    # if it is more than one file add it by using comma as separator

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new;

foreach my $file (@files) {
    my $member = basename $file;
    printf qq{Adding file "%s" as archive member "%s"\n}, $file, $member;
    $zip->addFile( $file, $member );
    printf "Member added\n";
}
printf "Writing to zip\n";
$zip->writeToFileNamed('zippedFolders.zip');
    #zip file name change it as u want
```

Comment: It might be producing errors, but you're not [checking for them](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Zip#ERROR-CODES).

Comment: its not producing any error, just the print output "member added" & "writing to zip." this is all i am getting on cmd

Comment: How would you know if there's an error if you're not doing any error handling?

Comment: Hey Matt, Please suggest me how to do that, or if there is other way to do zipping of files. I am new to perl.

Comment: Look at the link I posted in my first comment.

Comment: Adding below code in last  lines,  I am getting this error"Bareword "AZ_OK" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at D:\advapp\PSMAG\Scripts\Testing"                                               unless ( $zip->writeToFileNamed('zippedFolders.zip') == AZ_OK ) {
  die 'write error';
  }#zip file name change it as u want

Comment: any suggestion please

Comment: You have to `use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES );` in order to import the `AZ_OK` constant into your script. http://search.cpan.org/~phred/Archive-Zip-1.55/lib/Archive/Zip.pm

Comment: @MattJacob I added error codes, the code is still not throwing any  error and just printing all lines which are in printf but not generating the zip. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please:

```
use Cwd;
use strict;
use warnings;
# before running check perl module is installed in your PC.
use Archive::Zip;
use File::Basename;

my (@files,$dirname,$bsename) = "";
my $inFile = "D:\\Scripts\\Testing\\abc.txt"; # if it is more than one file add it by using comma as separator
my $curdir = getcwd();

#Need to open file here and to be read the file
open(IN, $inFile) || die "Cant \n";
while(<IN>) {
    my $sngfile = $_;
    chomp($sngfile);
    push(@files, $sngfile);
}
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
foreach my $file (@files)
{
    $dirname = dirname($file);
    $bsename = basename($file);

    #Check file exist here your code
    if($dirname!~m/\.$/) {
    print "$dirname\t$bsename\n";
    #printf qq{Adding file "%s" as archive member "%s"\n}, $dirname, $bsename;
    $zip->addFile("$dirname/$bsename"); }
}
printf "$curdir\\Writing to zip\n";
$zip->writeToFileNamed("$curdir/zippedFolders.zip"); #zip file name change it as u want
```

Comment: @ssr1012 I didn't give an answer. I was just trying to get at what the actual problem was.

Comment: @Matt Jacob: You have given the way to find out the answer. That's why I said already answer given by you. Apologies

Comment: @ssr1012 The code you gave as answer is not opening file also and directly going to die part printing "Cant".

Comment: @Sur: Please confirm the input file are available in the folder: eg: D:\Scripts\Testing\abc.txt. And please check the  edited code also.